# Detect values in bathymetry grid and output polygons - Python

Tags: python, csv, arcgis, shapely, geopandas

I have been supplied with a matrix of bathymetry (water depth) data. The matrix represents an evenly spaced grid of depths, and is in .csv format.

The matrix has some 'screened out' areas which have value -9999. The -9999 points need to be identified and turned into some kind of feature to be used later. The majority will be in clusters inside the grid - large areas of screened out data containing many (>1000) adjacent points. 
However...

- It could be that some or all of the outer edge values of the grid have value -9999.
- It is possible that there are lone points/lines of points which have value -9999.
- There are likely to be areas of -9999 surrounding regions of 'good' (not -9999) data - polygons within polygons.

**My task:** Identify each separate area (or point) of -9999 value within the csv file, and produce a separate polygon/point for each one. The polygons would be the outer/inner boundaries of the -9999 area

The next steps involve placing items on the map, avoiding the -9999 features.

I created my own function to identify the -9999 values and create polygons, but it has some issues, and I am sure there must be pre-built libraries which can do this better than I.

Can anybody advise a way to approach this, and perhaps give some useful library/function recommendations? I am beginning to doubt whether polygons/features are the way to do this, but that approach does seem to have some nice advantages if it can work.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have ArcGIS' Spatial Analyst extension?

Comment: Yes I do have access to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in 3 steps with geoprocessing tools:

1. Use [IsNull](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/is-null.htm) to create a new raster where NoData values are converted to 1 (and all other values to 0).
2. Convert your new raster to polygons with [Raster To Polygon](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polygon.htm).
3. Separate multipart polygons with [Multipart To Singlepart](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/multipart-to-singlepart.htm).

You can perfectly automate this workflow, either with [ModelBuilder](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/what-is-modelbuilder.htm) or with arcpy. If you are familiar with Python I advise you to use arcpy, check the code sample at the end of each tool's help page.

Comment: That's great. Thank you, I'll give it a go. But I was hoping I might be able to automate it with python. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: what about a solution which is completely free of GIS? I'd like to get away from that and use only python. Ideally. thanks!